# How to sort/group objects into lists based on distinctness of object variable value?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hash

I'm trying to figure out how to make a structure like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOgZm.jpg

Basically the list will hold lists containing objects whose "pickupTime" variables (date type) are equal. This means that (referencing the picture) "equal dates list 1" will contain all objects with equal pickupTime values, while "equal dates list 2" will do the same, HOWEVER "equal dates list 1" and "equal dates list 2" (and so forth) will have different values.

My use case is to be able to display on an interface a top level view showing distinct dates. Clicking/tapping one of these distinct dates will then show another screen that shows the objects that have that date.

My code currently is:

```
final Set<Reservation> setToReturn = new HashSet<Reservation>();
final Set<Date> set1 = new HashSet<Date>();

                for (Reservation res : result) {
                    if (!set1.add(res.getPickup_time())) {
                        setToReturn.add(res);
                    }
                }
```

This works fine to create a single list with ONLY distinct dates, however it does not sort objects with equal dates into their own groups, which I feel is somewhat beyond my scope of knowledge at this point. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a hash set, have you considered storing lists of objects inside the main list? (Might be a little easier to work with, at least imo)

For example: (Pseudo code)

```
get the pickuptime of the object
check to see in the main list if there is a list containing objects with that pickup time
if (above true) {
    add it to said list
} else {
    make a new list with that object
}
```

You can convert dates to strings if you need a name for new objects.

Here's a quick program I wrote to demonstrate the concept. It takes user input in the form of strings, and at the end of the program you'll see how the structure is printed out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<ArrayList> mainList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";

        // in this example, get user input to make a list with
        // you can easily change this to use .getpickuptime()
        // in this case, input would be replaced by the object.
        while (!(input = scan.nextLine()).equals("quit")) {
            // base case - if the list is empty make a new object.
            if (mainList.isEmpty()) {
                ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
                x.add(input);
                mainList.add(x);
            } else {
                boolean added = false;
                // check the lists to see if there's a matching value
                for (ArrayList x : mainList) {
                    // check each arraylists first object 
                    if (x.get(0).equals(input)) { 
                        x.add(input);

                        // change added to true
                        added = true;

                        // you've added the object so quit the for loop.
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // what if you went through all the lists and there was no matching list?
                if (!added) {
                    // make a new list.
                    ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
                    x.add(input);
                    mainList.add(x);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(mainList.toString());

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know if I get stuck. I definitely think lists within a list would be the easiest, but as far as efficiency I am unsure. Either way, it should still be able to achieve what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the reply, by the way.

Comment: Thanks @Aify. I used a slightly-modified version of this and it worked out great.